# Nuget.exe crashes when invoked from cmd.exe

Tags: cmd, rake, nuget

I'm trying to automatically download [`Nuget.exe`](http://nuget.org/nuget.exe) from a Rakefile, in order to minimize the amount of initial setup needed to run my samples on GitHub.

I've understand how to download a file (I'm using [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty)) and how to save a binary file (using the `b` flag on `File.new`) but now I've got problem running `Nuget.exe`. In particular:

- if I launch it directly or from PowerShell, the executable runs fine;
- if I launch it from `cmd` or from a Rakefile (which in turn runs `cmd`), Windows tells me that the program "stopped working".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced the same behavior with the [Nuget bootstrapper](http://nuget.codeplex.com/releases/view/58939), so I thought that the cause was some configuration in my computer.

It then occured to me that I installed [`ansicom`](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon), a library to handle ANSI sequences. I disabled it and then Nuget started without any problem.